# Migrated site's entries not updating

Tags: entries, update, migration

We have a site that was migrated to a staging environment.

For all the custom fields as well as the title/url_title fields, any edits/updates are not being saved. However, a new entry is being saved with the initially added content (then it becomes no longer updateable).

Has anyone come across this? Oddly, it's working just fine in our local environment.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Hi Jae! Can you expand on "not being saved".  ... you hit "Save Revision" or "Submit" in the edit interface and then what happens?

Comment: When I hit "Save Revision" or "Submit", it saves the entry but none of the updated content is retained.

What's odd -- a new entry can be saved and the initial data entered is retained. But when that's opened and edited, the edited content is not saved. 

This also seems to be a behavior on almost all fields, including title & URL title fields.

Comment: Could it be that the mysql user has INSERT but not UPDATE privileges on your EE schema?